# iOS/Swift & Coinbase Pro API - Subscribe to Websocket Feed

Tags: ios, json, swift, http, websocket

I am attempting to subscribe to a websocket feed using Swift. Per the new [Coinbase Pro API documentation](https://docs.pro.coinbase.com/#subscribe) for their websocket feed:

> To begin receiving feed messages, you must first send a subscribe message to the server indicating which channels and products to receive. This message is mandatory — you will be disconnected if no subscribe has been received within 5 seconds.

The first thing I did was add [Starscream](https://github.com/daltoniam/Starscream) to the project to make connecting to websockets easier to implement. I followed the steps on the README and added the delegate methods appropriately.

Next, I successfully sent an HTTP GET request (I get a 200 code in response) by creating a `URLSession` object and calling `dataTask(with: )` after setting up a request, like so:

```
    let session = URLSession.shared

    guard let url = URL(string: "https://api.pro.coinbase.com/users/self/verify") else {
        print("Could not create URL.")
        return
    }

    var request = URLRequest(url: url)

    request.httpMethod = "GET"

    let body: [String: Any] = ["type": "subscribe",
                               "channels": [["name": "heartbeat"],
                              ["product_ids": ["BTC-USD"]]]]
    let data = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: body,
                                                  options: JSONSerialization.WritingOptions.sortedKeys)
    request.httpBody = data

    let task = session.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in 
        // Check for errors, clean up data, etc.
    }

    task.resume
```

**Everything appears to be linked up correctly, but I am still not receiving the "subscription" messages from the websocket feed. What am I missing?**